# How do I write an installer for a .NET Windows application (need to install Access drivers)

Tags: .net, ms-access, installation

I am writing a C# Windows .Net application that reads/writes data from a Microsoft Access database.

How do I create an installer that will:

1. Prompt the user to install the file to a chosen directory
2. Install the files
3. Install Access (Office will not be present on users computers) - is this possible?
4. Install the version of .Net I am using

Is there a product from Microsoft that does this without costing an arm and a leg?

Comment: Search for "Microsoft Access DSN" and "Deployment Projects in Visual Studio"

Comment: We encourage not using DSNs as that's one more configuration step and chance for IT admin and/or user to fuddle up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to install Access?   Are you only using the Access database file to store data?  If so is this in MDB or ACCDB format?  If MDB format as created in Access 2003 and earlier then Jet 4.0, DAO 3.6 and ADO have been included as part of the operating system since Windows 2000.   If ACCDB format then you will need to install the freely downloable ACE DLLs as per [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en)

Now if you are actually using Access for forms and reports, and it's Access 2007 you can have your users install the Access 2007 runtime as per [Access 2007 Download: Access Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=D9AE78D9-9DC6-4B38-9FA6-2C745A175AED&displaylang=en)    Ahh, I see from your subject you specifically mention drivers.  Ignore this paragraph then.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment projects come with Visual Studio!

right-click on you solution and select add new project
Under Other Project Types select Setup and Deployment
Choose the setup and deployment wizard, it will step you through it.

Before you deploy, do a little googling on obfuscating your .net project, too.